# javascript countdown stutter

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a countdown like this one:

```
var countdown = {
    startInterval: function() {
        var count = 600
        var countorig = 600;
        var currentId = setInterval(function() {
            var min = (count - (count % 60)) / 60;
            var sec = count % 60;
            if (sec < 10) {
                $('#timer').html(min + ':0' + sec);
            } else {
                $('#timer').html(min + ':' + sec);
            }
            $('#time').val(countorig - count);
            if (count == 0) {
                $('#form').submit();
            }--count;
        }, 1000);
        countdown.intervalId = currentId;
    }
};
```

It works. But if I load the page, the countdown starts but it stutter it is not "round" like a clock is.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NerCD/).

Comment: You mean because it's called every second? You can call the set interval every 100 or 50 MS and account for that in your counting.

Comment: Do you have any working demo?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` isn’t exact. You should use `Date`s instead, to get an accurate time, and then choose an interval of less than one second to get a smoother clock. [Here’s a demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/XX75f/)

```
var countdown = {
    startInterval: function() {
        var count = 600;
        var start = new Date(); // The current date!

        var currentId = setInterval(function() {
            var difference = Math.max(0, count - (new Date() - start) / 1000 | 0);
            var min = difference / 60 | 0;
            var sec = difference % 60;

            $('#timer').text(min + ':' + (sec < 10 ? '0' : '') + sec);
            $('#time').val(difference);

            if(count === 0) {
                $('#form').submit();
            }
        }, 200);

        countdown.intervalId = currentId;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to assume your timers are exact. Instead, use delta timing.

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function() {
    var elapsed = new Date().getTime()-startTime;
    console.log("Been running for "+Math.floor(elapsed/1000)+" seconds");
},25);
```

Comment: Assuming you don't fire it right as it changes, `(new Date).getTime() === Date.now()`, and `Date.now()` has much less overhead than `(new Date).getTime()`

Comment: But `Date.now()` is not supported across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

That is because setInterval is not meant to be a high resolution timer. It will NOT hit every 1000 milliseconds on the dot. You might have swings as much as 20 to 30 milliseconds in either direction, resulting in a clock that is off.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Date.now()`, this is a quick example of a countdown function ( `x` is milliseconds )

```
function countdown(x){
    var o = {future: Date.now()+x, last:-1, i:null}; // object so we can pass by-ref if req.

    o.i = setInterval( function() { // use o.i so we can clear interval
        var remain = o.future - Date.now(),
            secs = Math.floor( remain / 1000 ),
            mins = 0;

        if( remain < 0 ){ // finished, do whatever
            return clearInterval(o.i); // then clear & exit
        }

        if( secs === o.last ) return; // skip this iteration if it's not been a second
        o.last = secs; // else update last time

        // do whatever you want for this new second
        if( secs > 59 ) mins = Math.floor( secs / 60 ), secs = secs % 60;
        console.log(
            (mins < 10 ? '0'+mins : mins) + ':' +
            (secs < 10 ? '0'+secs : secs) + ' remain.'
        );
    }, 100);
}
```

If you know it **wont** be used in IE, consider adding `o` as an argument to the callback function in the interval and also as the last argument to `setInterval` (so it is passed to the callback as first arg), which means closure is independent => callback can be defined anywhere.